# What is the mathematical relationship between MOSFET switching frequency (motor speed control) and motor speed in rpm?

Tags: motor, control

What is the mathematical relationship between the switching frequency of MOSFET in a three phase motor controller (induction motor and BLDC motor) and the speed in rpm of the motor shaft?

Comment: In a BLDC motor drive, there are two switching frequencies: the commutation frequency, and in most drive methods, a higher frequency switching with the goal of effectively applying less than the full supply voltage to the windings. There is also a third possibility: some BLDC motors with an integrated controller receive a speed or torque input through a PWM signal. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one really.

The switching frequency of the MOSFETs is a function of the inductance and resistance of the motor and is used to control current ripple (and therefore torque ripple).

The speed of the motor shaft is a function of how fast you change which of the three phases are being powered.

That being said, there are limits. For instance the switching losses incurred from a high switching frequency will limit the amount of power available to the motor and therefore limit the speed with which you can commutate the motor.